# Error in Unreal after Xcode Update : PCH file uses an older PCH format that is no longer supported

Tags: xcode, file, compiler-errors, unreal-engine4, pch

So I just recently updated Xcode(not too sure if this is causing the problem) to version 10.2. When I compile my code in Unreal Engine 4 version 4.21.2 it gives me this error. "PCH file uses an older PCH format that is no longer supported" Anything I can do to fix it?

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#pragma once

#include "Engine/TriggerVolume.h"
#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Components/ActorComponent.h"
#include "OpenDoor.generated.h"



UCLASS( ClassGroup=(Custom), meta=(BlueprintSpawnableComponent) )
class BUILDINGESCAPE_API UOpenDoor : public UActorComponent
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
    // Sets default values for this component's properties
    UOpenDoor();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public:
    void OpenDoor();
    void CloseDoor();

    // Called every frame
    virtual void TickComponent(float DeltaTime, ELevelTick TickType, FActorComponentTickFunction* ThisTickFunction) override;



private:
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    float OpenAngle = -90.0f;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    ATriggerVolume* PressurePlate;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    float DoorCloseDelay = 1.f;

    float LastDoorOpenTime;

    float GetTotalMassOfActorsOnPlate();
    //UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    //AActor* ActorThatOpens; //Pawn inherits from AActor
    AActor* Owner; //The owning door
    void FindPressurePlate();`enter code here`

};
```

I expect the game to compile to my newer version, actual result game does not compile.

Comment: Is there any progress ?